# TortoiseSVN: list of all commits for several repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a www folder with several websites in it, and all of these sites are committed though TortoiseSVn. Is there a way to output a list of all my commits for a certain period of time (recent week) for all sites in the folder? Ideally skip commits with same comment on them. Every site in the folder is an independent repository

It is not duplicate, as the other question asks for log for a single repository, not a whole folder of them

Comment: When I Google `TortoiseSVN: list of all commits` there seem to be a lot of useful links, have you tried them all and none worked for you?

Comment: yes, indeed i have, all advice there relates to a single repository, not a whole folder of them

Comment: But [this page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html) says: `The context menu for a folder allows you to: Show the revision log for that folder, or show a graph of all revisions so you can see where the folder came from.
` I'm on OS X at the moment so I can't test but I think I remember this working in TortoiseSVN

Comment: Is every site independent repository or not? Did you read about externals in SVN?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - it works only for Working Copy, while www-golder can be NOT WC, just container for WC

Comment: yes, every site is an independent repository